# Swipe action for custom dialog in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to implement swipe action for custom dialog in Android. Actually if I will swipe the dialog it should take to new activity.  If it is possible can anyone please explain me how to implement the same. Please remember I don't want to use any third party library to implement this. Thanks in advance

Comment: See this example:-  http://smartandroidians.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/dismiss-or-cancel-dialog-by-swipe.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CoordinatorLayout` to do this action since it has this behavior encapsulated.

Since you didn't post any code to base on, I'll show you how it can be implemented genrally (of course you'll have to put your dialog inside the `CoordinatorLayout` to get this functionality available on the dialog).
Try this:

### The XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/container">

<View
    android:id="@+id/dismiss"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="#3bb0ff"/>
```

### The code to use

```
View dismiss = findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) 
dismiss.getLayoutParams();
SwipeDismissBehavior<View> behavior = new SwipeDismissBehavior<>();
behavior.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_START_TO_END);

behavior.setListener(new SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final View view) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
        public void onDragStateChanged(int i) {}

});

params.setBehavior(behavior);
```